# Node js Error Handling it crash the server

Tags: node.js

Error handling in NODE JS

this is my Login Function

```
router.post('/admin/login', function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send('Error on the server.');
        if (!user) return res.status(404).send('No user found.');
        var passwordIsValid = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
        if (!passwordIsValid) return res.status(401).send({ auth: false, token: null });
        if (req.body.username && req.body.password) {
            console.log("enter");
            var token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, config.secret, {
                expiresIn: 86400 // expires in 24 hours
            });
            res.status(200).send({ auth: true, token: token });
        } else {
            return res.status(500).send('Error on the server.');
            //res.status(500).send("Check Username & Password");
        }
    });
});
```

if i forget to enter password the server will be crashed how to handle on this

Comment: Edit your question to include your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check to see if the password is being passed before you pass it into the `compareSync` function.

```
if (!req.body.password) {
// handle error
   return res.status(401).send("Missing or invalid password")
}
```

If you're doing this you should also check if `req.body.username` is being provided in the post request. Alternatively for easier method, you can have a `try catch` wrapped around the query to handle other unexpected errors.

Comment: Sending specific errors like this back to the client is bad practice. Authentication errors need to be as generic as possible; 'Username or password is invalid'.

Comment: @ethane you're definitely right. I just wanted to reply with something generic so that OP could get the gist of why he was having his error thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to check in front-end (client side) and also to check for email and password in back-end , there is various libraries to do that , for example i use express-validator lib here is a simple check and of course you can read full docs https://express-validator.github.io/docs/

code sample :

```
const { check, validationResult, body } = require('express-validator/check');

router.post('/admin/login',[check('email').isEmail(),check('password').isLength({ min: 5 })], (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }
 // the rest of your sing in code here 
})
```

and you can check for name length also this is safer for your back-end always check for validation in front-end and back-end, never trust client side only , do your own validation in the back-end , i hope this answer your question

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with a very similar code.
I replaced this line:

```
(...)
if (!user) return res.status(404).send('No user found.');
```

For this:

```
User.findOne({username : req.body.username},function(err, user){
        if(err){
            return res.status(401).json({message : err})
        };
        /* Trying to repair error when username is not on DB */
        if(user === null) {
            return res.status(401).json({auth : false, token : null, message : "Not Authorised User"});
        };
        /* Replacement worked */

        var isPasswordValid = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
```

Hope it works for you.